# JavaScript getElementsByTagName displaying [object HTMLParagraphElement] instead of the content of that element?

Tags: javascript, getelementsbytagname

Why is the following code displaying [object HTMLParagraphElement] instead of the element content? I have tried adding .innerHTML as well but this just displays undefined as well which is even more confusing. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated. 
Thank you

```
<form name="form1">
<p id="p1"> Paragraph 1</p>
<p id="p1"> Paragraph 2</p>
<p id="p1"> Paragraph 3</p>
<p id="p1"> Paragraph 4</p>

<input type="button" onClick="getElements();" value="Get elements"/>
</form> 

<SCRIPT language=javascript>
function getElements() {
var all = document.getElementsByTagName("p");

for (var i=0, max=all.length; i < max; i++) {
    alert(all[i]);
}
}

  </SCRIPT>
```

Comment: `alert` calls the `toString` method of the DOM element which returns `[object HTMLParagraphElement]` for the `p` element. Also your question is not related to Java.

Comment: Again it's terrifying where people still dig out ancient HTML markup ... onClick instead of onclick, missing quotes for attributes, and last but not least the exasperating `language=javascript`

Comment: @devnull69 you can go even further and remove the inline event handling. also closing paragraph tags are way old school. self closing input tags? not in HTML5 hombre.

Comment: Nope ... paragraphs need to be closed, but void elements (like input) *can*  be used in the self closing notation (http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#void-elements). So nothing wrong here ... But of course each `id` attribute needs to be unique in the document, so the multiple `id="p1"` are clearly wrong

Answer (score 2):

Please do not use `alert` like a debug statement. Use `console.log(all[i])` instead.

Also, `all[i]` references the whole element. If you want the content, use `all[i].textContent`.

Also, I have to advise you not to use inline JavaScript. It's ugly, and should be separated from the HTML. Use an event listener!

```
var btn = document.getElementById("input-tag-id-here");
btn.addEventListener("click", getElements, false);
```

If cross browser compatibility is an issue, older IE versions use attachEvent not addEventListener. But it's good practice to abstract your javascript from your HTML like that.

Comment: I want all 4 paragraph elements to be displayed seperately in a pop up window hence the use for alert()

Comment: Then you should know that `alert()` pauses execution. I suggest you use a modal window and not an alert. People see alerts on websites and they instantly lose credibility as a good website.

Comment: it is worth noting textContent is not supported by older IE (<=8). However I wouldn't go as far as giving a solution to a legacy browser.

Answer (score -1):

Use `all[i].textContent` or `all[i].innerHTML`